# Can a testNG test class extend from another class?

Tags: java, testng

Using java and testNG I have two tests in two different classes, test1.class and test2.class, and a base.class that contains most of the methods:

```
public class BaseTest {

@Test
public void step1() {

}

@Test(dependsOnMethods="step1")
public void step2() {

}

@Test(dependsOnMethods="step3")
public void step4() {

}
}

public class Test1() extends BaseTest {
@Test(dependsOnMethods="step2")
public void step3() {

}
}
```

I then runt a testng-test on test1.class but that wont work, it says 
"step4 is depending on method public void step3(), which is not annotated with @Test or not included"

I guess this is the wrong way to do this, but I can't figure out a better way. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a little counterintuitive. Without understanding what's going on in your tests, perhaps `step3()` should actually be an abstract method implemented in subclasses, and not an annotated test.

That way `step3()` will always get run since it's called from the base class and implemented in the subclasses.

Comment: Worked as a charm. I added abstract public Step3() in the basetest.class and annotated it with the @test. It worked very good